# INSERT com prepare não funciona

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tentando inserir dados no banco usando mysqli prepare mais não estão inserindo os dados, e não mostra erro algum

Perguntas:::

- Oque estou fazendo de errado nesse código abaixo?
- Essa é a melhor forma de se fazer?
- Poderiam colocar um exemplo?

  ```
  $conecta = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbdatabase);
  if($conecta->connect_error){
  echo "Conexao:<span class=\"ls-tag-danger\">Erro!</span>";
  }else{ 
  echo "Conexao:<span class=\"ls-tag-success\">OK!</span>";
  }


  $sql = $conecta->prepare("INSERT INTO cotacao (chave,id_transfer,id_empresa,nome) 
  VALUES (?,?,?,?)");  
  $sql->bind_param('s', $chave,$id_transfer,$idc,$nome); //    
  $sql->execute();
  $sql->close();
  $conecta->close();
  ```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro acontece no seu método `bind_param`, o método fala para o SQL qual é o tipo dos dados que estão sendo enviados à query e é obrigatório haver um para cada parâmetro que você enviar no bind. O `s` significa que o dado é do tipo string, `i` integer, `d` double e o `b` blob.

```
 $sql = $conecta->prepare("INSERT INTO cotacao (chave,id_transfer,id_empresa,nome) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?)");  
    $sql->bind_param('iiis', $chave,$id_transfer,$idc,$nome); //Supondo que a chave é um integer, se não ela também recebe um "s" de string    
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->close();
    $conecta->close();
```

Comment: OK  funcionou , verifiquei também se variável $nome estiver vazia o insert não funciona.  sabe o motivo?

Comment: @FabioHenrique Pode ser porque no banco ela esteja marcada como Not null.

Comment: Isso mesmo funcionou obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) que está ***errado/ou faltando*** os demais parâmetros, ***porque***, para cada item tem que ter o seu tipo definido, exemplo no seu código:

```
$sql = $conecta->prepare("INSERT INTO cotacao (chave,id_transfer,id_empresa,nome) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?)");  
$sql->bind_param('iiis', $chave,$id_transfer,$idc,$nome);
```

ou seja, faltou a declaração dos outros tipos que nessa [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) são 4.

[Os tipos são:](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

```
+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  i  | corresponde a uma variável de tipo inteiro                                    |
+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  d  | corresponde a uma variável de tipo double                                     |
+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  s  | corresponde a uma variável de tipo string                                     |
+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  b  | corresponde a uma variável que contém dados para um blob e enviará em pacotes |
+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo... mais verifiquei também se variável $nome ,$etc.. estiver vazia o insert não funciona. tem como deixar passar.  no insert antigo passava

Comment: @FabioHenrique vai depender de como está configurado na sua tabela, se esse campo for obrigatório então a SQL tem que ter valor, se não quebra a sua regra imposta nesse campo, na minha opinião se você acha que esse campo não deve ser obrigatório, vai no campo nessa tabela e deixe aceitar valores `null` !!! que vai resolver esse questão.

Comment: Isso mesmo funcionou obrigado

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cotacao SET chave = ?, id_transfer = ?, id_empresa = ?, nome = ?";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Tente assim, não esqueça de passar os parametros do array, ou usar normal mesmo.

Comment: da esse erro Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on string in